# ASUS EB1036 no video output after changing UEFI from "Windows 8" to "Windows 7"

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, boot, bios

I just bought an ASUS EB1036 desktop PC, which came with Windows 8.1 pre-installed.

[image]

Before downgrading to Windows 7, I changed an option in the UEFI BIOS from "Windows 8" to "Windows 7".

After rebooting (still with Windows 8 installed at this point), the computer did not output any video. I have tried multiple reboots but the problem persists. The monitor never wakes from standby. I've tried another monitor and the same thing happens.

Could this be related to the operating system option I changed in the UEFI BIOS? If so, how can I change this back if I am unable to view anything on the monitor in the first place?

In case this isn't clear enough: the main problem here is not that I can't get into the BIOS... it's that I can't see anything on my monitor. There is no video output.

Advice on how to access the BIOS is not helpful as *I can't see anything on my screen in the first place*.

Answer (score 1):

The bios user interface should show anyway. It is certainly not related to the operation system setting.

If your bios has a fast boot option, it is possible that it does not display the bios post screen.

If you remember the key to enter into bios ( probably del or f2 ), you could probably get into bios by hitting it in the first seconds of boot.
The problem is that the time might be too short, to easily get into bios.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the monitor isn't waking from standby mode or how I can fix this. As per the title, the main issue here is the fact there is no video output.

Comment: That's what I understood. I hoped it would help.

Comment: If I press delete or F2 to try to get into the BIOS, the monitor still refuses to wake up. As far as I can see, there's no video output no matter what I do. I'm still stuck!